# Recording when was macro used last time

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, tracking

is it possible to track somehow date/time of when was some specific macro used?

For example I have some macro assigned to button, so maybe track when that button was clicked?

Could you help me with that please?

Comment: "Yes it's possible".  Have the macro increment and record a count to persistent storage.  Other-wise this question is too broad (IMO anyway).

Comment: "When" implies a date/time; OP should have the macro retrieve the current sysdate/time when executed and save _that_ to persistent storage - which might well be a cell on a worksheet in the workbook that the macro is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, in theory, possible to change the VBA directly with a macro to store a date/time stamp in a constant and have it update every time; it is, however, a Really Bad Idea™ to do this.

As comments have said, your best bet would be to have a cell or cells in a worksheet to store your date/time stamp. For example, I often have a separate VeryHidden worksheet specifically for macro control. Let's say that we're using a sheet called "Tracker" for this purpose. The macro would start with something like:

```
Sub Whatever()
    'Constants
    'Variables

    Sheets("Tracker").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now

    '...
End Sub
```

This will keep a persistent record of every time the macro has been run. You can add other data alongside it at the same time if necessary.

Of course, if you just want to record it in the same cell every time, you can do that, too:

```
Sub Whatever()
    'Constants
    'Variables

    Sheets("Whatever").Range("Z42").Value = Now

    '...
End Sub
```